# Regex modifiers in Webmethods

Tags: regex, pipeline, webmethods, eai, modifiers

I am trying to use a regex pattern in Webmethods map step.
The problem is to ignore the case of matching string using regex modifiers.

E.g.:

> input is 'TEST' or 'test' or 'Test'

```
Branch on 'input'
/test/i : MAP
```

But as I read on different webmethods forums that using access modfiers in Webmethods is a limitation. So, I am unable to use '/i'.

Any idea or hint on how I could do it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: thanks @stribizhev :) it worked..!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can make use of the inline modifier `(?i)`:

```
/(?i)test/
```